# Please help to resolve the decorator issue in python

Tags: python-3.x

from below example , I'm trying to calculate performance of **long_time() and long_time2()** :

But Getting error saying **"TypeError: performance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fun':"**

```
from time import time

def performance(fun):
    def wrapper_fun(*args , **keyargs):
        t1 = time()
        res = fun(*args,**keyargs)
        t2 = time()
        print(f'took {t2 -t1} s')
        return res
    return wrapper_fun
    
    
@performance()
def long_time():
    print('1')
    for i in range(100000):
        i*5
        
        
@performance()
def long_time2():
    print('2')
    for i in list(range(100000)):
        i*5
        
long_time()

long_time2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `performance`. Instead of `@performance()` write `@performance`.

```
@performance
def long_time():
    print('1')
    for i in range(100000):
        i*5
```

The argument `fun` will be passed automatically with the usage as decorator (python calls the method).

Comment: Thanks @Sven Eberth